# invariance properties of lebesgue integration on any mesurable set

Tags: real-analysis

From Stein's book, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}f(y-x)dx$, but how we prove it is also true when the integration is on any measurable set *E*? I don't know how to use characteristic functions here...

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** true in the sense that

$$
\int_E f \, dx = \int_E f(y-x)\, dx,
$$

Because **you have to translate (and invert) $E$**:

$$
\int_E f \, dx =\int_\Bbb{R} f(x) \chi_E (x) \, dx = \int_\Bbb{R} f(y-x)\chi_E (y-x) \, dx =\int_{-E + y} f(y-x) \, dx,
$$

where I used te result for $f \cdot \chi_E$ instead of $f$, where $\chi_E$ is the indicator function of the set $E$.